# Dynamic Filtering in foreach (ASP.NET & EF)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a really simple case with a controller and a repository.

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductList(ProductQuery queryparams)
    {
        var products = await uow.ProductRepo.GetProductsWithQuery(queryparams);

        var productsToReturn = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductForListDto>>(products);

        return Ok(productsToReturn);
    }
```

Repository:

```
    public async Task<AbstractPagedList<Product>>GetProductsWithQuery(ProductQuery qp)
    {
        var products = DorianContext.Products
            .Include(p => p.Category)
            .Include(p => p.PriceOffers)
            .AsQueryable();

        // if (filter.CategoryId.HasValue)
        //     products = products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == filter.CategoryId);
        // if (filter.MinPrice.HasValue)
        //     products = products.Where(p => p.Price >= filter.MinPrice);
        // if (filter.MaxPrice.HasValue)
        //     products = products.Where(p => p.Price <= filter.MaxPrice);

        return await PagedList<Product>.CreateAsync(products, qp.PageNumber, qp.PageSize);
    }
```

Model:

```
    public class ProductQuery
    {
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public decimal? MinPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal? MaxPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Instead of the boring commented part, how can we structure a dynamic/generic logic to make filtering for CategoryId, MinPrice and MaxPrice. 
(For example in a foreach block of property list of ProductQuery)

Maybe we can use a dictionary object and a foreach like the following, but I am not really sure how to get Property Names as strings from the object (I tried to use NewtonSoft.JObject but without success)

```
        var filterMap = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>()
        {
            ["categoryId"] = (v => v.CategoryId == filter.CategoryId),
            ["collectionId"] = (v => v.ProductCollectionId == filter.CollectionId),
            ["minPrice"] = (v => v.Price >= filter.MinPrice),
            ["maxPrice"] = (v => v.Price <= filter.MaxPrice)
        };

        foreach (var key in filterMap)
        {
                products = products.Where(key.Value);
        }
```

I don't want to use reflection. Ideas or comments with the best practices of such a case are also appreciated.

Comment: Would it make sense to encapsulate the logic of generating an expression for the `filter` object, as a method on `filter`?

Comment: What you're actually doing is fine. What do you mean by "boring"?

Comment: @ZevSpitz, yes it makes sense but first of all I need to find a solution to the problem of taking the string representations of property names (of ProductQuery to match the cases)

Comment: @CodeNotFound What I did works yes and I can continue just like this but this will result lots of duplicated logic. And because this is a toy project, I am searching for the ways to improve it. And such a project, this is overkill I agree..

Comment: _string representation of property names of `ProductQuery`_ AFAIK, the only way to do this is via reflection. Even if you convert the object to `JObject`, I am quite sure that Newtonsoft JSON is using reflection under the hood.

Comment: I think what you're trying to achieve is over complicating it. Anything you do will hide away logic, which is better in plain view with the logic already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I did works yes and I can continue just like this but this will
>   result lots of duplicated logic. And because this is a toy project, I
>   am searching for the ways to improve it. And such a project, this is
>   overkill I agree..

So the best way to avoid to break the DRY principe is to create a `Filters` property into `ProductQuery` class like this:

```
public class ProductQuery
{
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public decimal? MinPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? MaxPrice { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>> Filters
    {
        get 
        {
            var filters = new List<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>();

            if (this.CategoryId.HasValue)
                filters.Add(p => p.CategoryId == this.CategoryId);
            if (this.MinPrice.HasValue)
                filters.Add((p => p.Price >= this.MinPrice);
            if (this.MaxPrice.HasValue)
                filters.Add(p => p.Price <= this.MaxPrice);

            return filters;
        }
    }
}
```

So in your code you can use it like below:

```
public async Task<AbstractPagedList<Product>>GetProductsWithQuery(ProductQuery qp)
{
    var products = DorianContext.Products
        .Include(p => p.Category)
        .Include(p => p.PriceOffers)
        .AsQueryable();

    foreach(var filter in qp.Filters)
    {
        products = products.Where(filter);
    }

    return await PagedList<Product>.CreateAsync(products, qp.PageNumber, qp.PageSize);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the local list variable need to be of `Expression<Func<Product, bool>>`?

Comment: Indeed fixed. It must be a `List<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>`

Comment: _best way to avoid to break the DRY principe_ for which value of _n_? :)

Comment: @ZevSpitz I added it because of the comments of the OP. I'm not working in his project. He said he want to avoid duplications so the sample in the question doesn't represent the real project he is working on. Maybe he is right about duplications so my answer here to help him for not breaking DRY principe. You can contact him and have more details about his project :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a value tuple, of test-function and expression pairs:

```
ProductQuery filter = ... // initialize here

var exprs = new List<(Func<ProductQuery, object>, Expression<Func<Product, bool>>)>() {
    (f => f.CategoryId, p => p.CategoryId == filter.CategoryId),
    (f => f.MinPrice, p => p.Price >= filter.MinPrice),
    (f => f.MaxPrice, p => p.Price <= filter.MaxPrice)
};

foreach (var (test, expr) in exprs) {
    if (test(filter) != null) {
        products = products.Where(expr);
    }
}
```

---

You could go even further, by parsing the expression tree (e.g. `p => p.CategoryId == filter.CategoryId`) and seeing which member(s) of `filter` are being used (e.g. `filter.CategoryId`). Then, you could apply the condition only if that member has a value:

```
ProductQuery filter = ... // initialize here

var exprs = new List<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>() {
    p => p.CategoryId == filter.CategoryId,
    p => p.Price >= filter.MinPrice,
    p => p.Price <= filter.MaxPrice
};

foreach (var expr in exprs) {
    var pi = ((expr.Body as BinaryExpression)
        .Right as MemberExpression)
        .Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (pi.GetValue(filter) != null) {
        products = products.Where(expr);
    }
}
```

This way, you can avoid defining the null-checking test.

The code which parses the expressions should probably be more flexible -- what if the filter property is first in the expression? what if there are conversions involved somewhere?

---

I would also suggest encapsulating the logic of building a single filter expression as a property of `ProductQuery`:

```
public Expression<Product, bool> Filter => {
    get {
        // implementation at end of answer
    }
}
```

which you could then call without any loops:

```
products = products.Where(filter.Filter);
```

You could implement this yourself, but I highly recommend using the [LINQKit PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

```
public Expression<Func<Product, bool>> Filter {
    get {
        var exprs = new List<Expression<Func<Product, bool>>>() {
            p => p.CategoryId == this.CategoryId,
            p => p.Price >= this.MinPrice,
            p => p.Price <= this.MaxPrice
        }.Where(expr => {
            PropertyInfo mi = ((expr.Body as BinaryExpression)
                .Right as MemberExpression)
                .Member as PropertyInfo;
            return mi.GetValue(this) != null;
        });

        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Product>();
        foreach (var expr in exprs) {
            predicate = predicate.And(expr);
        }

        return predicate;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I use FilterType?

Comment: @ElHuracan It was just a placeholder; I hadn't noticed the `ProductQuery` type in your question. Updated.

Comment: in the tuple example, how is filter defined?

Comment: @AussieJoe I've fixed it.`filter` is an instance of `ProductQuery`.